# Как осуществить фильтрацию объектов модели по значениям связанного моделя?

Tags: php, laravel, объекты, octobercms

Есть две модели: Tovary, Category.
Они связаны между собой по belongsToMany.

Требуется оставить все товары нужных категорий. 
Например все товары категорий с id: [1,4,7]

```
use avtor\Plugin\Models\Tovary;    

function onStart(){         

       $categoryes=[1,4,7]; //id нужных категорий
       $Tovary = Tovary::get();// все товары

      $nuzhnyeTovary = Tovary::whereIn('????', $categoryes)->get();  

}
```

????  - как обратиться к столбце модели Категории?

Comment: Вероятно просто сделать `$nuzhnyeTovary = Tovary::where('category.categoryId in ' . $categoryes)->get()`? Чтобы вам было понятнее, старался излагать, в стиле вашего кода.

Comment: ошибку выдает.

in разве внутри where может быть? 
Нашел whereIn
   `$nuzhnyeTovary = Tovary::whereIn('category.categoryId', $categoryes)->get();`
 но также ошибка:  Неизвестный столбец category.categoryId

Comment: Так все верно. Поставьте название своего столбца, где вы храните id категории. Код я написал чисто для размышления для вас, а как вы реализуете у себя, решать вам

Comment: в модели Товары этого столбца и нет. А как обратится к столбце модели Категории?

Comment: Все верно. Но что такое belongsToMany? Вероятно это метод, который, магическим образом генерирует JOIN? Может быть такое? Ведь эти таблицы имеют нечто общее? Если да, то если попробовать указать имя столбца id таблицы категорий, то вероятно, мы получим необходимый результат.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

нужно использовать whereHas

```
$tovary = Tovary::whereHas('category', function($query) use($categoryes){  $query->whereIn('id', $categorys);}) ->get();
```